# How to get banner in header to flow behind logo? Needs to be responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am having some issues getting my header images to flow correctly. This is a responsive WP theme.

Here is the design I am trying to achieve. (I am not worried about the social icons right now):  http://screencast.com/t/0xJuqKuteU

First, I need the message bar with the redish background to flow under the logo and beyond the banner like this: http://screencast.com/t/CZ4DkbRA50R

Then for both the banner and the message bar, I need them to work better when the screen is shrunk down to phone size. This his how I need it to look on a phone: http://screencast.com/t/z5BQ7zB4

Notice the banner comes in right below the navigation and the message bar goes away.

Here is the site I am working on: http://dev.frugalreality.com

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

To make the message bar "float" underneath the logo, you need to set the containing div css (#header-callout) to have `position:relative;` and set the z-index to something negative (`z-index: -1` should do). This creates a layering in the divs and puts the message bar below all other divs (unless you set something else to a lower z-index).

For displaying things differently on the iPhone screen size I would suggest using a media-query. If you don't know how to use those, I suggest browsing through this article to get a better idea of what I mean: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

In order to NOT display the message bar, you will have to put `display:none` for the #header-callout in the css of the appropriate media-query.

Answer (score 0):

Having a screen CSS and Media/Phone CSS page should help in managing the two different screens.